# Why does introducing numbero in minikanren cause the failure of valid unifications?

Tags: logic-programming, unification, minikanren

I am using Racket v8.5, with the packages for minikanren and
minikanren/numbers required. Why does introducing the numbero
constraint cause previously valid unifications to fail?

```
> (run 1 (q) (<lo '(1) q))                                                                                                                                                                                                        
'((_.0 _.1 . _.2))                                                                                                                                                                                                                
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
> (run 1 (q) (<lo '(1) q) (numbero q))                                                                                                                                                                                            
'()                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
> (run 1 (q) (numbero q) (<lo '(1) q))                                                                                                                                                                                            
'()                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
> (run 1 (q) (<lo q '(1)))                                                                                                                                                                                                        
'(())                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
> (run 1 (q) (<lo q '(1)) (numbero q))                                                                                                                                                                                            
'()                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
> (run 1 (q) (numbero q) (<lo q '(1)))                                                                                                                                                                                            
'()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the `numbero` constraint enforces that a term is consistent with a number in the host language (Racket in this case).  Think of `numbero` as the constraint equivalent of Racket's `number?` predicate: `(numbero 5)` succeeds.  However, you are using Kisleyov's relational arithmetic system, in which numerals are represented as little-endian lists of binary digits: `(numbero '(1 0 1))` fails, just as `(number? '(1 0 1))` returns `#f` in Racket.